# How do I plot a bar chart where values are missing?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to pull data from the UN Comtrade database (using package comtradr) and then plot it.

I know as always there's a simple solution to this, but I can't work it out.

I can grab the data, reshape it and plot. But because there are NA values in some rows for India and the USA, I think those final bars are being removed from the plots.

I've tried adding na.rm = TRUE to the geom_bar arguments, but that isn't working for me.

I also get the warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
2: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

Which I think must be related, but I've searched it and don't fully understand.

Any advice welcome.

Code below which should be reproducible if you install comtradr.

```
# Notes.------------------------------------------------------------------------

options(scipen=999)

# Packages.---------------------------------------------------------------------

library(tidyverse)
library(comtradr)
library(patchwork)

# Extract export data with query.-----------------------------------------------
# I know this should look nicer, but the API has limits on how you can query and
# this is my quick/dirty solution.

df_a <- ct_search(
  reporters = c("China", "USA", "India", "Germany"),
  partners = "World",
  trade_direction = trade_list,
  freq = "annual",
  commod_codes = "2501",
  type = "goods"
)

df_b <- ct_search(
  reporters = c("Australia", "Canada", "Chile", "Mexico"),
  partners = "World",
  trade_direction = trade_list,
  freq = "annual",
  commod_codes = "2501",
  type = "goods"
)

df_c <- ct_search(
  reporters = c("Russian Federation", "Brazil"),
  partners = "World",
  trade_direction = trade_list,
  freq = "annual",
  commod_codes = "2501",
  type = "goods"
)

# Select relevant columns from extracted dataset.-------------------------------

df_a2 <- df_a %>%
  select(year, qty, trade_value_usd, reporter, trade_flow)

df_b2 <- df_b %>%
  select(year, qty, trade_value_usd, reporter, trade_flow)

df_c2 <- df_c %>%
  select(year, qty, trade_value_usd, reporter, trade_flow)

# Join datasets.

df <- bind_rows(df_a2, df_b2, df_c2)

# Pivot data.

df_import <- df %>% 
  select(reporter, year, trade_flow, qty) %>% 
  filter(trade_flow == "Import") %>% 
  group_by(reporter) 

df_import2 <- aggregate(df_import$qty, list(df_import$reporter), mean) %>% 
  rename(Country = Group.1) %>% 
  rename(Count = x) %>% 
  mutate(Count = Count / 1000)

df_export <- df %>% 
  select(reporter, year, trade_flow, qty) %>% 
  filter(trade_flow == "Export") %>% 
  group_by(reporter)

df_export2 <- aggregate(df_export$qty, list(df_export$reporter), mean) %>% 
  rename(Country = Group.1) %>% 
  rename(Count = x) %>% 
  mutate(Count = Count / 1000)

# Build plots from extracted data.----------------------------------------------

import_plot <- ggplot(data = df_import2, aes(x = reorder(Country, Count), y = Count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightblue", na.rm = TRUE) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()

export_plot <- ggplot(data = df_export2, aes(x = reorder(Country, Count), y = Count, fill = "red")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#de4048") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()

import_plot / export_plot
```

Comment: How do you want to handle the NA values? Replace the NAs with 0 or another value?

Comment: I would like to replace them with zero, I think it is reasonable given there are few missing values.

Comment: I see what you're getting at -- I can add %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) to the returned dataframes (e.g. df_import) and then the bar charts are plotted nicely.